# When passing an object to a class' method, does it need to be *defined* as a constant?

Tags: php, class, object, properties

What I mean is do I need to use `define()` to set the object before passing it to the method of my class? Or is it considered constant when passed because it is being used by reference? I think I have a misunderstanding of the manual's information.

```
class User
{
    private $pdo = false;
    ...
    public function __construct($pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    ...
}

$pdo = new PDO(...);
$user = new User($pdo);
```

vs

```
class User
{
    private $pdo = false;
    ...
    public function __construct($pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    ...
}
define(MYPDO, new PDO(...));
$user = new User(MYPDO);
```

I was reading the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) in reference to properties that are objects and it states that the initialization must be constant so that it can be evaluated at compile time.

After reading it a few times, it shouldn't matter which way I do it, because it does not get instantiated within class definition.

If I understand it correctly, the case the manual refers to is defining the object within class definition rather than passing the value to a property.

I am currently passing the PDO object to each function as I use them, so I wanted to try to pass it once, at construction instead. Or, is that a bad idea?

I'm not sure if there's any benefit to doing it either way, I'm just trying to understand OOP better.

Comment: If you're using a non-dead version of PHP, it's passed by reference and the first option would work. However, the second version wouldn't work because your construct is still expecting a variable... but more importantly, because you can't define a class as a constant. Passing in the constructor is called dependency injection and is a very common way to do it. ^^

Comment: @Jon Sorry, I missed removing the getByUserName method. It's fixed.

Comment: Ah Ok. You still shouldn't be able to assign a constant as the class though. That code should fail at [`define(MYPDO, new PDO(...));`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real reason to use `define()` in this use-case.

Injecting the objects that you're going to use in another class upon construction is definitely the right way to do it. There is also method injection, but at that point it's just a matter of preference.

In other words, you don't want to instantiate a new object inside a class; you should create it elsewhere and inject it in. This allows for better decoupling of your code, and improves maintainability going forward as you'll be able to swap out large pieces of your application easily and effortlessly.

Best way to do it, in my opinion, is like this:

```
class User
{
    /** @var PDO */
    private $pdo;
    ...
    public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    ...
}

$pdo = new PDO(...);
$user = new User($pdo);
```

Where the `PDO` in the `__construct()` method is a type-hint for the type of object the method will accept, and the `/** @var PDO */` isn't necessary, but helps for IDEs (and people reading your code) to understand what your property is supposed to be once it is set.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understood the practice correctly correctly. I was using my first method, but I think I misunderstood what the manual was saying because they used the word "constant". I thought I was doing it wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you were doing it right, I'm glad to hear! It usually takes people a long time to figure out dependency injection, so that's awesome. Though I do recommend type-hinting objects whenever you pass them in.

Comment: You just gave me something new to look at, thanks. Now I'm wondering if I inject my User object to another object, and change a property value, will it be reflected in the other object's usage of it?

Comment: @Dexter Yep, it will.

Comment: @Jon Awesome! guess that's the value of passing by reference! Thanks guys for your help!

Comment: @Dexter for clarity, objects in PHP are always passed by reference, as opposed to a string or array where you'd need to define it as `&$myReferencedArray` in a function's arguments instead